# Ionic cordova build android failed: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, compilation

I'm doing an app on Ionic. The problem is when I want to compile for Android. It gives me an error. I've tried a lot of things and it doesn't work. I'm new in this and maybe I'm doing something wrong, so that's why I'm asking for your help. I'll put all the information here, so I hope you can help me.

I'm using windows 10. This is the error that terminal shows me

```
    > cordova.cmd build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\cesal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231 (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
D:\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyecto Fashioner\Aplicacion\fashioner-app\Fashioner\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

The information of my Ionic is this:

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.2 (C:\Users\cesal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.10.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.11.3
   OS     : Windows 10
```

The requirements of cordova are these:

```
cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-28,android-27
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-5.6.4\bin\gradle
```

So, I'm not sure if the problem are the environment variables of the system. I added as I saw in different forums, but it doesn't work. Here you have the screenshots:

[my environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W7dD.png)

And this is my PATH variable:

[PATH Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Efqc.png)

Please help me, I don't know what to do with this problem. I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Try with --verbose option to debug the error

Answer (score 3):

I spend almost 2 days to find solution

Please remove this in environment variable

hopes it work

`CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL`

Comment: I did have that environment variable with an older version of Gradle. Removing it made me use the newer version and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up the project from android studio then rebuild.

Comment: And how can I do this? I'm new in this. Please be more specific

Comment: On Android studio top menu, you will find build, click it to see the drop down, down of the list you will find clean, and then rebuild. hit clean first then when its done, rebuild lets see.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all folders that are not related to the project. I mean, folders like node-modules, platforms, plugins... That kind of folder (anything that could be inside a `.gitignore`). Then, use `npm install` and wait until it finishes. Test if everything works (using `ionic serve` if you like) and try again. That worked for me.